# ¿Cómo reemplazar texto por el resultado de una función?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, regex

En mi base de datos tengo un campo que contiene una plantilla HTML, la cual tiene valores que debo reemplazar. Por ejemplo:

```
<div>{nombre}</div> <!-- Salida: <div>Carlos Huchim</div>-->
```

Sin embargo, mi interés es vincular una imagen, pero que la ruta no sea fija, si no que se ajuste de acuerdo a la página que se esta viendo usando `UrlHelper`.

Este es mi intento:

```
<img src="#fn_image&id=1" /> <!-- Salida: <img src="Banner/Image/?d=&id=1 />-->
```

```cs
internal static string Parse(string data)
{
    var data1 = data.Replace("#fn_image)", GetUrl("#fn_image"));
    return data1;
}

internal static string GetUrl(string type)
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case "image":
            return GetUrlHelper().Action(
                "Image", 
                "Banner", 
                new { d = "BLCM01" })
                .Replace("BLCM01", string.Empty);
            break;
        default:
            return GetUrlHelper().Action(
                "Image",
                "Banner", 
                new { d = "BLCM01" })
                .Replace("BLCM01", string.Empty);
            break;
    }
}
```

¿De qué manera puedo reemplazar el texto, usando algo como lo siguiente?

```
<img src="fn_image(1)" /> <!-- Salida: <img src="Banner/Image/1" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deberías utilizar una expresión regular en la que captures el número y devuelvas la url con el número capturado:

```
    internal static string Parse(string data)
    {
        var pattern = @"fn_image\((\d+)\)";

        return Regex.Replace(data, pattern, GetUrlHelper().Action("Image", "Banner", new {id = "$1"}));
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @asier-villanueva, tuve un pequeño problema porque mi intención era poner la variable en lugar de $1, pero con tu ayuda, me di cuenta de que podía usar un delegate y con este [artículo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18906514/) pude extraer los parametros y terminar de armar la URL. Muchas gracias.